# Reverse of matrix multiplication when matrix is non-invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

In [factor analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_analysis), a random variable can be expressed as:

$$
\mu(y) = \beta^TX+\epsilon \\
Var(y) = \beta\Sigma\beta^T+Cov(\epsilon)
$$

where $\beta \in R^{N \times M}$ is factor loadings and $\Sigma \in R^{M \times M}$ is factor variance-covariance matrix. I'm working on a machine learning application where I need to learn $\Sigma$ but during learning it can become non-invertible. So I'm trying to write the second equation in terms of $\Sigma$ to see if it helps. It's been too long since I last did matrix algebra but my first attempt is this:

$$
\Sigma = \beta^{-1}(Var(y) - Cov(\epsilon))(\beta^T)^{-1}
$$

The problem is $\beta$ isn't a square matrix so it's not invertible. Apologies for the dumb question but how do you rewrite the second equation in terms of $\Sigma$?